# Disable bluetooth Ubuntu 20.04 Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, raspberrypi

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 64bit (headless) on a rpi 4 8gb and I'm having some problems with bluetooth (I think). The rpi seems to affect my apple tv 4k remote, which is connected trough bluetooth. My rpi is located about 30cm from my atv. When my rpi is running, the bluetooth remote doesnt work well. When I shutdown my rpi, the remote works fine. As soon as my rpi is booted up, the remote starts acting up again.

My suspicion is that the bluetooth module in the rpi is interfering with the atv remove. I'm not using any bluetooth features on my rpi, so I want to disable the bluetooth on the rpi completely. I've edited the `/boot/firmware/usercf.txt` and added:

```
dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
```

But the interference still occurs. Also, I've uninstalled all bluetooth related software. Is there a command to see if there is any bluetooth module running? Or should I disable bluetooth with another method? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `rfkill` ?

You will need to run it as `sudo` ( `sudo rfkill` ), and for (soft)blocking Bluetooth, i.e.: `sudo rfkill block bluetooth`.

`sudo rfkill list all` should bring up a list of devices that can be soft blocked.

That *ought* to do it for the soft kill side. You still might need to make it persistent so that it doesn't get reverted on next reboot (see i.e.: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=146198 )

You can also try disabling the device with `iwconfig` and `ifconfig` as described in the thread linked above. Try the `rfkill` at first though, and see if that solves the problem, then look into the other options to make it permanent.

As an example, you can get a list of available devices by typing `ifconfig` in terminal. Bluetooth should usually be listed there as `bt0` .

`sudo iwconfig bt0 txpower off` should turn off the transmission (="Tx") power to the selected unit (`bt0` in this case.)

After that, try `sudo ifconfig bt0 disable` - you can then re-list your network/RF devices with `sudo rfkill list all` to see their status.

In any case, utilizing a combination of `rfkill` , `iwconfig` and `ifconfig` (as `sudo`) should do the trick in disabling any BT or WLAN devices in your system that you wish to turn off.

Comment: `sudo rfkill list all` doesnt show anything to block. I've tried `iwconfig` and `ifconfig`, both of them don't show any wireless devices.

Comment: Sorry, the problem seems to be related to the usb 3.0 interference https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/io/universal-serial-bus/usb3-frequency-interference-paper.html When I connect my external drive to the 2.0 ports on the rpi, the problem is gone. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Gijs - as a side note to solve *that* issue, note that the source of USB3-based interference can also be in the cabling and/or attached devices. Things usually boil down to shielding and/or grounding issues (i.e.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_loop_(electricity) - asymmetrical or no ground potential can cause accumulation of RFI/EMI interference.) A good .pdf presentation on the topic from AES a.k.a. the Audio Engineering Society can be found from: http://audiosystemsgroup.com/AES-RFI-SF08.pdf . I would recommend using a good enclosure on the RPi4B as well (i.e. Argon One.) Good luck!

Comment: I've wrapped the usb3 cable in aluminium foil and the issue is solved! So the cable doesnt seems to be shielded. I'm going to replace it with a shielded cable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure bluetooth is really disabled using the edit to `/boot/firmware/usercf.txt` you described?

In the [official config.txt docs](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html) I find `dtoverlay=disable-bt` which seems to be working on my Rpi4. Look at the [model filter](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/config_txt.html#model-filters) section too.